# How can I save array of object and reuse with same values once I opened my app again. #Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   defaults.set(memes, forKey: "HI")

}

var memes = [ViewController.Meme]()
```

I wrote this code in my AppDelegate and reload the values in the tableview using this code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let token = defaults.array(forKey: "HI")?.count
   print(token ?? -1)
}
```

But I can't see the array is filling with anything I'm using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the ordering wrong. In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching(_:)` you first need to add items to your array and *then* store it as follows:

```
var memes = [ViewController.Meme]()
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(memes, forKeyL "HI")
```

And then you can read it as you currently are in your view controller

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you saved an empty array.

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```swift
//  if (by whether your array is full)
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let memesKey = "memesHI"
defaults.set(memes, forKey: memesKey)
```

**`viewDidLoad()`:**

```swift
var memes = [ViewController.Meme]()
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
private let memesViewKey = "memesHI"
let memesArray = [Any]()
memesArray = memes
let token = defaults.array(memesArray, forKey:memesViewKey)?.count
```